# Can I use an array in ajax javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I'm new with ajax and I want to use an array in ajax.

What I want is:

1. get data from ajax
2. add data to new Array. It's all.

`$(document).ready(function () { var main_img = new Array()});`

So, first, I made one new Array and It works very well.

Than I made `settings` variable for my ajax:

```
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:52273/movie",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "postman-token": "b39e3106-5289-f828-261f-132e1aba7bf7"
    }
  }
```

localhost runs in node server.js and I will get data from html.

```
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $('#content > div.article > div > div.lst_wrap > ul > li > div > a > img', response).each(function(index)
    {
      var k = $(this).attr('src');
      var k2 = k.slice(0, k.indexOf('?'));
      var alt = $(this).attr('alt');

      main_img[index] = k; // this is not working!!!
    });
  });
```

setting and ajax run on `document.ready`,

and I test insert value in out of ajax, it works very well..

So I thought something is wrong when I use an array in ajax.
Please Help me...

Is there anything I am missing???

Comment: use `main_img.push(k)`

Comment: MysterX -> I understand It's another way to add array data, and It doesn't work.. Sorry..

Comment: So your ajax call executed earlier then `$(document).ready`

Comment: Why do you have `$(selector, response)`? Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You mean, My ajax is run before $(document).ready right? no, My Code is like, $(document).ready(function(){ var main_img = new Array; var setting = {~} ; $.ajax(settings).done ~~ }// ready end .. I think ajax run after document ready

Comment: Rajesh >> response is all data from ajax setting, so its data of localhost:52273.. and there's just some html data. and I want to get img src string data from there. the link of page is like this : https://movie.naver.com/movie/running/current.nhn

Comment: @jameslee When you say HTML data, I assume its html string. If you wish to search through it, you will have to create an in-memory element and search through it. Since its in-memory, it will not affect the DOM. try `var responseContainer = document.createElement('div'); responseContainer.innerHTML = response or some property of it`. Not search through it

Comment: what is the error and what do you want to acheive?

Comment: @Rajesh ok, I'm try it now.. Thank you for comment rajesh! TAHA SULTAN TEMURI problem is I cant edit my array in ajax, and I want to add a value of data from ajax, to my array with index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since it is possible to have this bug hidden out of sight, what I would do will be:

1. Create a var to store the type of what I think is an image: `let test = typeof(k);`
2. Use `main_img.push(test)` as [MysterX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527537/mysterx) just said.
3. Then `console.log(main_img)`.

I hope it helps!

Then probably it is about scope, let's try this:

`$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    $('#content > div.article > div > div.lst_wrap > ul > li > div > a > img', response).each(function(index, main_img)
    {
      var k = $(this).attr('src');
      var k2 = k.slice(0, k.indexOf('?'));
      var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
      main_img[index] = k; // this is not working!!!
    });
  });`

Comment: OK, I try it. variable k is src of img tag, so it is string. and It doesn work when use main_img.push(test) in ajax, but it works when I Use main_img.push(test) out of ajax... Thanks for reply!